# unable to access wp-admin after change theme on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i cannot access wp-admin, and i search on internet and it suggest me to delete the first blank space on file function.options.php, but there it not blankspace. how should i do ?

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>
> (output started at
>   /home/voalahui/public_html/wp-content/themes/rebound/admin/functions/functions.options.php:1)
>
> in /home/voalahui/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1207

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when i open function.option.php

```
<?php
add_action('init','of_options');
if (!function_exists('of_options'))
```

line 1 there is not blank space to deleted

so, i reupload again my file to hosting, and make sure there is not file who failed, and it's fixed